# Woher kommt das Wort Eitz

Tags: meaning, etymology

Ja da gibt es den *Eitz* in der Nähe von Weissenhaus in Schleswig-Holstein, eine Steilküste an der Ostsee. Keiner scheint zu wissen, wo das Wort seinen Ursprung hat.

Comment: Bitte editiere deine Frage, indem du mehr Info zur Verfügung stellst. Was kann das Wort bedeuten? Wer verwendet das Wort?

Answer (score 9):

Die Ortsbezeichnung *Eitz* taucht schon in alten topographischen Karten 1:25.000 (Meßtischblatt 365, neue Nr. 1630 : Hohwacht) aus dem Jahr 1879 auf.

Der Begriff wird als Flurname entstanden sein und bezieht sich sicherlich auf das Waldstück mit einem (früheren) alten Eichenbestand.

[image]

> "An Hand eines lehrreichen Flurnamenmaterials hat H. WESCHE gezeigt, dass ein wichtiges nordseegermanisches Merkmal des Altniederdeutschen, die Assibilierung des palatalen `k` und `g` (im 19. Jahrhundert auch "Zetazismus" genannt) in ostfälischen und nordniederdeutschen Mundarten tiefgreifender war, als man bisher angenommen hat. Abweichend von HANS KUHN, der die [Palatalisierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalisierung) von k und g durch südenglischen Einfluß auf den Kontinent erklären möchte, sieht WESCHE darin eine gesamtnordseegermanische (nicht speziell sächsische) Erscheinung.
>
> Dass die assibilierten Formen längst nicht alle im 13. Jahrhundert wieder aufgegeben wurden, wie A. LASCH in ihrer grundlegenden Untersuchung über "Palatales k im Altniederdeutschen" (Neuphilologische Mitteilungen 40) auf Grund der Ortsnamen annahm, zeigt der Verfasser an Hand vieler bewahrter Flurnamen mit den Elementen E(t)z-, **Eitz-** ‹eki 'Eiche', Bötz-, Bütz- ‹böki 'Buche', Bätz-, Beetz- ‹biki 'Bach', Spetz- ‹speckia 'Knüppeldamm', Sprötz- ‹sproke, sprake 'Reisig', Quitze- ‹quike 'Vogelbeerbaum', Ütze- <*ükia 'Kröte', Sever- ‹kever 'Käfer', Silken- ‹külken, kölken, kalken 'Holunder' und einigen anderen."

In: [Niederdeutsches Wort](https://www.lwl.org/komuna/pdf/Niederdeutsches_Wort_01_1960.pdf), Kleine Beiträge zur niederdeutschen Mundart und Namenkunde, Herausgeber WILLIAM FOERSTE, Band 1, Verlag Aschendorff, Münster, 1960

[image]

Zum Vergleich füge ich auch den aktuellen Kartenausschnitt von [OpenTopoMap](https://opentopomap.org/#map=15/54.30269/10.76950) bei, der an die amtliche topographische Karte 1:50.000 angelehnt ist.

Comment: Wie ist die Endung *-t-z* zu erklären, die augenscheinlich nicht von \*eki kommen kann, aber gleichfalls in den anderen zitierten Ortzbezeichnungen auftaucht? Sieht slawisch aus ("Chemnitz", "Döberitz", "Prigniz", "Berlin-Köpenic", "Prenzlau", etc). Zudem kann ich weder *s* < *k* wie in *Sever* < *kever*, noch die Aufhebung des *k* wie in *biki* > *Bee-*, *Bä-* oder eben *eki* > *Eitz* ohne weiteres nachvollziehen. Bitte um Aufschluss, aus welcher Zeit stammt der Name nun?

Comment: Ja, bin mir nicht ganz im klaren wo diese Antwort herkam. Auf jeden Fall vielen Dank. Habe aber in der Zwischenzeit auch rausgefunden das Eitz eventuell was mit Lebensbaum, Baum, Holz  zu tun hat (Genesis 2.9 altes Testament- Garten von Eden- Hebrew)

Comment: @Peter - wenn die Antwort passt, ist ein upvote und die Markierung als Antwort gern gesehen.